# End date as selected startdate in foundation datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Defaultly, startDate and endDate as showing the current date. I want t make the end date as selected start date not the current date.

Please look at this fiddle,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9C4F/)

Here, defaultly it has showing current date in both startdate and enddate filed.
For example, If I select startDate as "12-12-2017", I want end date as start with "12-12-2017" only not today's date.  How can I do this.

```js
var nowTemp = new Date();
      var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
      var checkin = jQuery('#startDate').fdatepicker({
          format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
          onRender: function (date) {
              return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
      }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
              if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
                  var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                  checkout.setValue(newDate);
              }
              checkin.hide();
              jQuery('#endDate')[0];
          }).data('datepicker');
      var checkout = jQuery('#endDate').fdatepicker({
          format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
          onRender: function (date) {
              return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
      }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
              checkout.hide();
          }).data('datepicker');

          jQuery("#startDate,#endDate").fdatepicker({
              autoclose: true,
              format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
              language: 'de',
              todayHighlight: false
          });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="start_datum" class="input_text date"   value="" >
    
<input type="text" id="endDate" name="end_datum" class="input_text" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this, I hope this solves your problem
     -
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du0a6tyu/)

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
      var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
      var checkin = jQuery('#startDate').fdatepicker({
          format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
          onRender: function (date) {
              return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
      }).data('datepicker');
      var checkout = jQuery('#endDate').fdatepicker({
          format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
          onRender: function (date) {
              return date.valueOf() < checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
          }
      }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
              checkout.hide();
          }).data('datepicker');

          jQuery("#startDate,#endDate").fdatepicker({
              autoclose: true,
              format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
              language: 'de',
              todayHighlight: false
          });
```

Comment: End date is displayed on change of startdate. I don't want like this. After selecting end date only I want to display the end date. Can you please change this,.

Comment: Now it is not working. Please see that blue color active date still showing the current date. I want that active date as an startdate.

Comment: For example If I select startdate as "20/10/2016", and Now If I open end date picker, I want to start with "20/10/2016" only. Not today date.